# How do I make mysqldump output using the SET col_name= syntax

Tags: mysql

Using `mysqldump`, can I make it generate an SQL file that uses the `SET col_name=`syntax?

I have tried various `--skip-inserts` and `--extended-inserts` combinations but don't seem to be able to get there.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: To be able to edit the dump and filter out certain columns quickly to move it to a different database with a similar but not the same structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge this is not possible. What you can do, is to use [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) and [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html).

It's also very fast. Give it a try.

Comment: Any recommended way of doing this so you can just select columns that exist in another table?

Comment: You'd have to use dynamic sql. So you'd have to write a stored procedure that queries `information_schema.columns`, build a query string with it and execute it with a prepared statement.